# Sharepoint 2007 - search

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint site.. in that i have uploaded many docs...

When i perform a search by giving a keyword, its showing some docs which dont have that word.

I dnt know the reason for it..

Can anyone please help me to find the reason?

-Poorani

Answer (score 0):

Keyword searches search a document's *content* in addition to its *metadata* (where applicable).  Is it possible that the keyword is contained somewhere in the documents contents?

Comment: Is the keyword you're searching for AND or OR?  There are certain words that are considered "noise" and will be omitted from your search, thus returning everything.

Comment: im searching with only one keyword.. if that keyword is present, then that document has to be returned..
Now, the search result is giving me 2 docs for that keyword search...Of which, one doc is having that keyword, but the other doc is not having that keyword, not in metadata properties also
..